# Function for an arbitrary number of arguments gives type error

Tags: python, function, math, lambda, tuples

I want to write code to calculate Pythagoras' theorem for an arbitrary number of arguments. Here:

```
>>> pythag = lambda *x: sqrt(sum(x**2))
```

I want the code to be executed simply by typing in:

```
>>> pythag(x,y,z)
```

where `x`, `y` and `z` are different integers and you can type in as many as you want. However, when I call this i get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'.
```

I can't figure out why Python thinks I'm presenting it with tuples. I remember writing a functioning code for this a couple of days ago but I didn't save it anywhere. I can't seem to come up with it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You configured your lambda to accept an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
lambda *x: ...
```

The `*x` means *capture all positional arguments for which there is no formal argument*. Python does this by making `x` a tuple, containing 0 or more captured positional argument values.

You could easily see this if you created a lambda that just returned the values:

```
>>> echo = lambda *x: x
>>> echo(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> echo('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
>>> type(echo('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
<class 'tuple'>
```

So `x` is the `tuple` here, containing the 3 integers you passed in when you called the lambda. You can't use the `**` power operator on a tuple, which is why the `x ** 2` expression raises the `TypeError` exception.

If you wanted to produce the sum of each of those integers raised to the power of 2, you'd need to use a loop:

```
lambda *x: sqrt(sum(i ** 2 for i in x))
```

Note that it doesn't make much sense to *calculate Pythagoras' theorem for an arbitrary number of arguments*; the theorem applies to a fixed number of inputs, you can't just generalise that to an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 1):

`(1,2,3)**2` is not valid python

to see what happens try this

```
def a_func(*x): 
   print(x)

a_func(1,2,3,4,5)
```

to fix it you can do something like this

```
pythag = lambda *x: sqrt(sum(y**2 for y in x))
```

will do a list comprehension that goes and squares each int in the list that is passed in , and then it will sum those values, and lastly it will take the sqrt of that sum ...

Answer (score 1):

you probably want this:

```
from math import sqrt

pythag = lambda *lst: sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in lst))
```

`lst` will be assigned to the tuple `(1, 2, 3)` if you call it this way:

```
pythag(1, 2, 3)
```

and python does not know that to do with `(1, 2, 3)**2`. that's why you need to iterate over the elements of the tuple.